# xcode 5, cant submit app. Unable to authenticate package

Tags: iphone, ipad, storyboard, app-store-connect, xcode5

I have been working on an update to an app I already have in the app store. All I have done is added some extra view controllers in another storyboard. (I already have a few storyboards in my app and have always added them without any issues). Everything compiles and runs fine (both in the simulator and on a device) but when I go to submit to the app store it fails validation saying that it cannot find "MainStorybaord_iPhone~iphone.storyboardc"... which to me doesn't even make sense since its not even an iPhone app... It's an iPad App... Is there some new requirement that we have to include an iPhone storyboard even for iPad Apps? Any help would be appreciated.. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I've also had this recently, except mine's an iPhone app getting a "missing iPad storyboard" error.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the storyboard from the plist file if you use iPad

```
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
```

or if you use iPhone

```
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad</key>
<string>Main</string>
```

Comment: You have to go to your plist file and remove the storyboard that are not used in your project.. If you have iphone application remove the ipad storyboard... if you have ipad remove iphone storyboard